# Export SharePoint List with Managed Metadata column as CSV using PowerShell

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell

I am using the script below to export a 6000+ item Sharepoint list to CSV. It works great, however, 1 of the columns on the list is a Managed Metadata column. When exported with the script below, the values are all 'Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Taxonomy.TaxonomyFieldValue'.

I have tried a few variations but I am struggling. Please could anyone help me to change the script below to work with the Managed Metadata column?

```
Function GetAllListItems($ctx,$listUrl)
{
   #Get the List
    $List = $Ctx.Web.GetList($ctx.Web.ServerRelativeUrl + "/" + $listUrl)
    $Ctx.Load($List)
    $Ctx.ExecuteQuery()
 
    #Define Query to get List Items in batch
    $Query = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.CamlQuery
    $Query.ViewXml = @"
    <View Scope='RecursiveAll'>
        <Query>
            <OrderBy><FieldRef Name='ID' Ascending='TRUE'/></OrderBy>
        </Query>
        <RowLimit Paged="TRUE">5000</RowLimit>
    </View>
"@
 

    $allListItems = @()
    #Get List Items in Batch
    Do
    {
        $ListItems = $List.GetItems($Query)
        $Ctx.Load($ListItems)
        $Ctx.ExecuteQuery()
        #$ListItems.count
        $Query.ListItemCollectionPosition = $ListItems.ListItemCollectionPosition

       foreach($listItem in $ListItems)
       {
            $allListItems += $listItem
       }


    }
    While($Query.ListItemCollectionPosition -ne $null)

    Return $allListItems


}


Function MainProcress()
{

    $siteUrl = "SITE URL HERE"
    $listUrl = "Lists/List Name Goes Here"
    $outputFilePath = "F:\exportedlist.csv"

    $includeHiddenField = $False
    $includeReadonlyField = $False

    Connect-PnPOnline -Url $siteUrl -Interactive

    $ctx = Get-PnPContext
    $ctx.Load($ctx.Web)
    $ctx.ExecuteQuery()

    $listFields = Get-PnPField -List $listUrl |? { $_.Hidden -eq $includeHiddenField -AND $_.ReadOnlyField -eq $includeReadonlyField} | Select -ExpandProperty internalname

    $count = 0

    $listItems= GetAllListItems -ctx $ctx -listUrl $listUrl

    $listItems.Count
    $hashTable=@()  

    # Loop through the list items  
    foreach($listItem in $listItems)  
    {   $count = $count+1
        Write-Progress -Activity "Exporting" -Status "$($count/$listItems.Count*100)% Complete:" -PercentComplete $($count/$listItems.Count*100)
        $obj=New-Object PSObject              

        $listItem.FieldValues.GetEnumerator() | Where-Object { $_.Key -in $listFields }| ForEach-Object{ 
                                        
                    if($_.Value.LookupValue){$obj | Add-Member Noteproperty $_.Key $_.Value.LookupValue}
                    else{$obj | Add-Member Noteproperty $_.Key $_.Value}                                        
                    
                   
                }
        
        $hashTable+=$obj;  
        $obj=$null;  
    }  
     $hashtable | export-csv $outputFilePath -NoTypeInformation  

}

MainProcress
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd create a new object for each list item in the loop and fill it with data I need.